# In which dialects has "right" been used as an adverb meaning "very"?

Tags: word-usage, british-english, adverbs

I, as an American English speaker, have the intuition that "right" could mean "very" in some British or Australian dialects. However, I could not find much information outside of a couple of dictionary entries that simply list it as dialectical or archaic usage.

For example, the [entry from the free online Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/right) does indeed identify this usage of "right" as archaic and dialectical usage, though the [entry in Merriam Webster's online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right) provides this usage with no qualifiers. Meanwhile, [the entry in dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/right) provides no indication of that usage whatsoever.

Comment: This is a *right honourable* question. It should wear one of those powered wigs and have a mini gavel.

Comment: Right (adv.)  [mid-19C+] (also rite) used for emphasizing how good or bad someone or something is, e.g. a right bastard, a right good ’un.

Comment: @user159691 That usage isn't really equivalent to "very", it's more like "proper", "real" or "true". In fact "a proper bastard" and "a real good 'un" are both common expressions.

Comment: *Right now. Right then. Right by Joe's. Right after her. Right there. Right here. Right out the door. Right next door. Right up your alley.* There’s also the use of *right* in the sense of the longer word *downright*, which is more directly equivalent to *really* or *very*: “That's a downright silly idea” > “That’s a right silly idea”.

Comment: I suggest the real question would be, in which dialects has it not…?

That's by no means to say *right* and *very* are always or even usually interchangeable but still *rightly, that's a very different point* works just like *verily, that's a right different point*.

Comment: If you are asking about dialects, I would say the same thing that the free online Oxford Dictionary says: archaic English.  Its usage in modern English is associated more with righteousness or correctness.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be non-standard yet with quite a spread in both the US and Britain.
Regarding "Right Honorable", I see the temptation to equate it with "very", but "Right Reverend" would point away from that as a definitive equivalance. It certainly turns up the volume.
It is worth noting that *recht* in German is far more standard in this usage as an emphasizer. Perhaps rather than "very" you could consider "quite" a better translation.